# GLSL Vertex Shader causes either flashing colors or all red

Tags: function, opengl, fixed, vertex-shader

I'm writing my first vertex shader for a (*here it comes*) homework assignment and can't get it to function properly.

I need to implement a vertex shader (and only a vertex shader) than completely mimics the fixed function pipeline vertex shader in openGL, and use the FFP fragment shader (so write nothing for a FS).  I am aware of built-in uniform variables, and I'm using them to calculate a vertice's final color based on the openGL lighting equation.  I've renamed some of the values for readability's sake (normal and lightVec are normalized):

```
    //given as part of the assignment, not modifable
    vec4 position = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    //my (partial) code below here

    lightVec = (lightPos - position).xyz;
    distance = length(lightVec);
    vec3 normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;

    //I've stored a lot of the values in variables I defined locally
    //to make the code easier to read.
    //eg - constAtten = gl_LightSource[].constantAttenuation

    atten = 1/max((constAtten + distance*linearAtten + distance*distance*quadAtten),1); 
    ambient = ambInt * matAmbInt * atten;
    diffuse = difCol * matDifInt * max(dot(normal, lightVec),0.0) * atten;
    specular = specInt * matSpecInt * atten * pow(max(dot(normal, (gl_LightSource[i].halfVector).xyz),0.0), gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
```

I'm summing ambient, diffuse, and specular for each light in the scene and storing it as "sum", followed by:

```
    gl_FrontColor = gl_FrontMaterial.emission + sum;
    gl_FrontColor.a = 1.0;
```

The result is crazy flashing colors every time I move the scene's camera.  This is openGL v1.2.

Edit: Link to picture

http://i305.photobucket.com/albums/nn208/wolverine1190/shadercomp_zpsc546ac31.png

Whenever I move the camera, the colors on the left change.  Could that possibly indicate an incorrectly calculated normal, or possibly the use camera coordinates somewhere I shouldn't have?

=================================================================

## **Resolved**

I've fixed the issue.  Not exactly sure why it works now, but it does.  I scrapped everything and re-wrote the code from scratch with the same approach and calculations.  What I did differently is:

1) I set values with constructors instead of just assignment.  Eg - instead of vec3 test = someOtherVec3,  I did vec3 test = vec3(someOtherVec3).

2) When normalizing I assigned the normalized result of a variable to itself instead of just calling normalize().  Eg - instead of normalize(normal), normal = normalize(normal);

3) I added to gl_FrontColor directly at each step instead of storing intermediate values in sum and adding sum to gl_FrontColor at the end.

Other than that, everything stayed the same.  I can't say for sure why that fixed things, so if someone does know please comment with an explanation.

Comment: Can you post the fragment shader?

Comment: There is no fragment shader that I'm writing.  The default fixed function fragment shader is used.

Comment: Post a picture of the problem.  It might ring a bell for someone.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I wonder if your colors are overflowing.  What happens if you try:

```
    gl_FrontColor = clamp(gl_FrontMaterial.emission + sum, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: No dice, still the same result.  As a side note, I've updated my final calculation to include global ambience, so now it's

`gl_FrontColor = gl_FrontMaterial.emission + gl_LightModel.ambient*gl_FrontMaterial.ambient + sum;`

If I remove sum from the equation, the problem is gone, but nothing is lit properly.  It's all very dim.  I checked the length of sum (to check for overflow) and it's not a very large value at all so I'm unsure why it's causing problems.

Comment: I'm wrong anyway: I checked and they're clamped implicitly by OpenGL.

Comment: So I've discovered something interesting.  As long as the values in the vector "sum" are not zero, I have the problem.  It doesn't matter how small all the values are, if they are any greater than zero I have the flashing colors.